Python typing annotation return value annotation based if function argument being a list or not
If I have
   def get(
        ids: str | list[str] | int | list[int],
    ) -> float | list[float]:

Is there a way to specify in return value annotation that a list of floats is output only when the input ids is a list of strs or ints?

typing module doesn't directly allow for conditional annotations that depend on the input type ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload ...Explore  @overload concept ... using @overload, you can define multiple function signatures to specify the relationship between input and output types..

This question is similar to: How can I type-hint a function where the return type depends on the input type of an argument?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

One way to do this is by using the @overload decorator to create 2 extra function signatures, one for int | str that returns float and one for list[str] | list[int] that returns list[float] and then have the actual function definition like you have now.
from typing import overload


@overload
def test(
    ids:str | int,
) -> float:...

@overload
def test(
    ids:list[str] | list[int],
) -> list[float]:...

def test(
    ids: str | list[str] | int | list[int],
) -> float | list[float]:...


Your get is really two different functions. One converts its argument to a float; the other uses the first to convert a list of arguments to a list of floats.
def get(x: str | int) -> float:
    ...


def gets(xs: list[str] | list[int]) -> list[float]:
    return [get(xs) for x in xs]

You only feel compelled to combine them into a single function (for "convenience") because Python lacks a built-in function that makes gets easy to create on the fly from get.
def listmap[A, B](f: Callable[[A], B]) -> Callable[[list[A]], listB]:
    return lambda xs: [f(x) for x in xs]

floats = listmap(get)([1, "2", 3])

This is an example of "inversion of control": instead of making get decide what to do based on the type of its argument, you decide which function to call based on the type of the argument.
